# Bash_shell Use shell to convert three format in one script to another script at one time

Tags: shell, awk, sed

```
cat file1.txt
set A B 1
set C D E 2
set E F 3 3 3 3 3 3

cat file2.txt
A;B;1;
C;D.E;2;   
E;F;3 3 3 3 3 3;
```

please help convert the format in file1.txt to file2.txt, the file2.txt is the output. I just input 3 lines in file1.txt for taking example, but in fact ,there are many command lines same with these 3 format.So the shell command should be adapt to any situation where the content contains these 3 format in file1.txt.

Comment: what are the rules?  why there is a dot between D and E instead of semicolon?

Comment: yes. it is the rule that when one line contains three words like "C D E",except "set" and number , the second word will connect the third word with dot ,not semicolon;when one line contains two words like "A B" , except "set"  and number, the two words will connect with semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "set A B 1
set C D E 2
set E F 3 3 3 3 3 3 " | sed -r 's/set (.) /\1;/;s/([A-Z])*( ([A-Z]))/\1.\3/g;s/([A-Z]) ([0-9])/\1;\2/;s/ ?$/;/'
A;B;1;
C;D.E;2;
E;F;3 3 3 3 3 3;
```